# How to prepopulate credit card form with customers name in Magento?

Tags: onepage-checkout

In the checkout, how can one add the customer's name to the credit card form? Is there a way to get the customer name int the checkout page?

What I would like to do is have the customer's name during the checkout process to use in the steps.

For instance:

- Like, "Hello Joe, this is step 3"
- "You still with us Joe this is step 4"
- In the credit card form add their billing name with a little "x" to clear it 
  if they want to use their uncles card.

How do I read the billing name to use it like this? The name appears in the progress bar so I thought that might work (as I don't show the bar).

It should be for all users, guests especially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the customers name in the checkout and do something useful with it, get the name from the customers billingdata, which is saved in the quote. `Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getName()`

The file you need is `app/design/frontend/{YOUR_PACKAGE}/{YOUR_TEMPLATE}/template/payment/form/ccsave.phtml` (you can copy it from `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/payment/form/ccsave.phtml`)

Add in the top of the file: (line 26)

```
$ccOwner = $this->getInfoData('cc_owner');
if (empty($ccOwner)) {
    // Update cc_owner from billing address
    $this->getMethod()
            ->getInfoInstance()
            ->setData('cc_owner', Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getName());
}
```

To add the X to empty, add the next after the input field:

```
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Name on Card')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_owner" name="payment[cc_owner]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getInfoData('cc_owner')) ?>" />
        <a href="#" onclick="jQuery(this).prev().val(''); return false;" />X</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works great.  Is there a way to get the X inside the field? Not a big deal though. Thank you

Comment: I got the x in the input field just using css.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

to get the current (logged in) customer details:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
   $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
}
```

The resulting object will contain all the customers details.

Not sure what you want to do with the sidebar....

Comment: Thanks, what I would like to do is have the customer's name during the checkout process to use in the steps also. Like, "Hello Joe, this is step 3", "You still with us Joe this is step 4" then when they get to the credit card form their billing name will be in the credit card form with a little "x" to clear it if they want to use their uncles card. Is there a way to capture the billing name to use like this? The name appears in the progress bar so I thought that might work (as I don't show the bar). Something like that. But for all users even guest especially to add to the card form.

Comment: Tye information given is what you need. You need to adjust the relevant templates to insert the customer information into the form fields as default, or adjust relevant titiles of sections.